# Why is plt.scatter causing recurrent error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, eclipse

I am updating the plot with `plt.scatter` in every iteration. But suddenly it started giving an error. I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'kwargs' from 'matplotlib.offsetbox'
>   (C:\Program Files(x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py)

Here is the code:

```
d=math.sqrt((z1[0]-z2[0])**2+(z1[1]-z2[1])**2) 
plt.subplot(2,1,1) 
plt.scatter(x,y,s= 40, marker='o', alpha=0.5, c='g') 
plt.plot(dx,dy, 'ro--', linewidth=2, markersize=5 ) 
plt.title('Trial:'+str(trial)) 
plt.xlabel('X Coordinate of Particles.') 
plt.ylabel('Y Coordinate of Particles.') 
ax=plt.gca() 
ax.set_xlim(-3,20) 
ax.set_ylim(-3,20) 
plt.subplot(2,1,2) 
plt.plot(best_Obj, 'bo--', linewidth=2, markersize=5) 
plt.xlabel('Iteration') 
plt.ylabel('Efficiency')
```

Comment: Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please state your code so we can analyse it.

Comment: d=math.sqrt((z1[0]-z2[0])**2+(z1[1]-z2[1])**2)
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.scatter(x,y,s= 40, marker='o', alpha=0.5, c='g')
    plt.plot(dx,dy, 'ro--', linewidth=2, markersize=5 )
    plt.title('Trial:'+str(trial))
    plt.xlabel('X Coordinate of Particles.')
    plt.ylabel('Y Coordinate of Particles.')
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.set_xlim(-3,20)
    ax.set_ylim(-3,20)
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(best_Obj, 'bo--', linewidth=2, markersize=5)
    plt.xlabel('Iteration')
    plt.ylabel('Efficiency')

Comment: @Debasish Please don't add information in the comments. Instead update your question.